# How to add variable minutes to a given date?

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

I have the next query (I'm using postgresql):

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP fecha_cita + cast((select tiempo_intervencion from cita_intervencion) as interval) 
from cita;
```

What I'm doing here is basically taking a date like this '2001-09-28 01:00' from the 'cita' table (that's what fecha_cita is) and I want to add more time to this complete date, in this case 'tiempo_intervencion' is something like '120 minutes' but this information is in a different table called 'cita_intervencion', the problem is that since these are variables dates and times and not a fixed date, things like `SELECT TIMESTAMP '2010-11-19 01:11:22' + INTERVAL '120 minutes` doesn't work for me, I get errors like:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "fecha_cita"
>   LINE 1: SELECT TIMESTAMP fecha_cita + cast((select tiempo_intervenci...
>   ERROR:  cannot cast type d_entero_p to interval
>   LINE 1: ...ct tiempo_intervencion from cita_intervencion) as interval) ...

I've looked up on google for some information on this and I was trying to follow [this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-datetime.html), but I can't find anything that can solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a join and then cast the string to an interval:

```
SELECT c.fecha_cita, fecha_cita + ci.tiempo_intervencion::interval
from cita c
  join cita_intervencion ci on c.id = ci.cita_id;
```

This assumes that there is some column in `cita_intervencion` that links that back to the `cita` table. If you really do not have that you can do something like this:

```
SELECT c.fecha_cita, fecha_cita + (select tiempo_intervencion::interval from cita_intervencion)
from cita c
```

But that will **only** work if `cita_intervencion` contains *exactly* one row.

The casting to an interval will only work if the values in `tiempo_intervencion` follow the rules for an interval.

You do not need the `timestamp` keyword for columns already defined as a `timestamp` that is only needed to introduce a timestamp literal (constant) value.

---

> *SELECT TIMESTAMP '2010-11-19 01:11:22' + INTERVAL '120 minutes doesn't work for me*

That works if you add the missing `'` for the interval literal:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2010-11-19 01:11:22' + INTERVAL '120 minutes'
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use:

```
select DATEADD(MINUTE,120,GETDATE())
```

Comment: This is invalid for Postgres (and even if that worked in Postgres, it's not what Marco asked for. The interval to add is stored in a second table.